# Magento 2 - How to reload sections on admin sales order create page on page load?

Tags: magento2, admin

I want to reload all sections on admin sales order create a page, on page load event. How can I do that? I have tried manually when making the change in an input field of billing sections, then an ajax call triggers

```
Call: http://test.com/admin/sales/order_create/loadBlock/key/2e92cb3383a1ccc651701e3b066848829b38f0093743a9ea8740aedde1eee7ed/block/billing_method,shipping_address,totals,giftmessage,items?isAjax=true
```

How can this call be trigged on admin sales order create page on load?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The  case is not clear

Comment: It's really simple when you go to admin sales order create page, and make change in any billing address field there is a ajax call triggers for refreshing all sections on the page. I want that ajax to be triggered on page load. I have mentioned ajax call in description. Hope it clears your doubt.